# proxychains in linux is not working

Tags: proxychains

On terminal when i use proxychains firefox it is getting terminated instantly by showing this.
[image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: Which version of Kali (I suppose it is Kali) are you using?